# RNTN: stop training early on convergence?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently training some sentiment analysis models with [the RNTN within CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html). With the default settings, training runs for 400 iterations which takes a long time. Is there some way to stop training earlier, e.g. if the error does not get smaller? Is there code which allows this?

In the 2013 paper by Socher et al, there is a sentence stating that the RNTN convergences after a few hours of training. Can I exploit this?

---

edit for clarification:

The paper I am referring to is "Recursive Deep Models for Semantic Compositionality Over a Sentiment Treebank" by Socher et al, EMNLP 2013. The RNTN I refer to is part of the Stanford CoreNLP package.

To rephrase and clarify my question:

**How can I make `edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining` stop training when the model is "good enough" (for some criterion) instead of going through all 400 iterations?**

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is this paper? Could you show us relevant parts of it and try to rephrase what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Magnilex thank you for your question. The stanford-nlp tag is tracked by the Stanford NLP group to whom the question will be clear. Of course, this is a general forum so I added some much-needed clarification.

Comment: @MichaelHaas, I don't see any such option in the source code (there are only options for limiting iterations / total training time). I might be missing something, though.. you might have more success making direct contact with Richard Socher, who managed the code but has now left Stanford.

Comment: @JonGauthier Thanks, I have sent him an email.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the code does not automatically detect when it is no longer improving in order to terminate the run early.  However, it does output intermediate models.  If you train using a dev set, you can keep the model with the highest dev score at the end of the run.